# WP7 AppTile Title still showing

Tags: xml, windows-phone-7

WP7 is gone since quite a time. But I still have an app I keep updating for WP7-Users.
Normally, following works. But For some reason the app title won't hide

```
<PrimaryToken TokenID="AppToken" TaskName="_default">
        <TemplateType5>
          <BackgroundImageURI IsRelative="true" IsResource="false"></BackgroundImageURI>
          <Count>0</Count>
          <Title>  </Title>
        </TemplateType5>
      </PrimaryToken>
```

As you can see, the Title-Tag is empty. But still it shows the apps name on the tile.
Why?

Comment: Did my post help at all?

Answer (score 0):

To hide the app title on the tile, can you right click on the solution file, go to properties and just set the text of the tile to nothing?